# Excel macro with variable row input based on date

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up a `macro` which for the sake of argument works like this:
Monitoring daily sightings of specific birds. `Column 'A'` represents the days date with `column 'B'` and up representing different birds.
I have a button in each column with a keyboard shortcut for each button.
What I want is for the button when clicked to add 1 to the cell in the appropriate row for the day.
So on the 20th Jan, the button would add to one cell, and on the 21st, the cell below...

I've search for clues on this but am drawing a blank. Any ideas?

Comment: It would help us if you could demonstrate what you are doing. Try to upload an image of the sheet and use MSPaint to indicate whatever you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I've written up a bit of code, this code assumes that Column A is dates in the format of "m/d/yyyy", Row 1 is a listing of the different birds you're traking via the sheet, and that you have Forms buttons on that same sheet with the name of the bird that matches what you have in Row 1 **exactly**. (e.g., C1 you have "Brown Wren", you then have a forms button that has "Brown Wren" as the text on it)

```
Option Explicit
Public ws As Worksheet

Private Sub AddBirdSighting(ByVal rng As Range)

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Invalid range"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    rng.Value = rng.Value + 1

End Sub

Private Function GetRange(ByVal Bird As String, ByVal Today As Date) As Range

    Dim c As Integer
    Dim r As Integer

    c = ws.Range("1:1").Find(Bird, LookIn:=xlValues).Column
    r = ws.Range("A:A").Find(Today, LookIn:=xlValues).Row

    Set GetRange = ws.Cells(r, c)

End Function

Public Sub CommandButtonClick()

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim ctl As String
    Dim btn As String

    ctl = Application.Caller
    btn = ws.Buttons(ctl).Text

    AddBirdSighting GetRange(btn, Format(DateTime.Now, "m/d/yyyy"))

End Sub
```

Copy/paste this code into a module in VBA, and assign the CommandButtonClick procedure to all of the buttons. If you need any of this explained let me know and I'll go into more detail.